# Extracting multiple rpm files and overwrite existing files

Tags: 14.04, extract, rpm, file-roller

I have a bunch of rpm files in a directory, where all rpm files are extracted as /usr/..
I would like to extract all rpm files and overwrite existing files.

I normally do that with file-roller -f *.rpm which brings up the GUI to ask the location to extract and then doing its work. 
As file-roller is crashing on 14.04 (last time i did this was on 12.04) im searching for another way to do this work

If i use the file-roller GUI (selecting all rpm files in nautilus) and say extract here this will result in having several folders usr, usr(1), usr(2) ... usr(102).

Is there any app or another way i can use?

Comment: You don't want to use RPM package files, ubuntu uses DEB packages and you should install from the repository.

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/view-and-extract-packages/

Comment: @xangua i dont want to install any rpm package on debian based systems i just want to extract mutiple rpm packages with a single comand and overwrite existing files

Comment: @Elder Geek thanks for the link so combinding rpm2cpio and cpio should do the trick. So is there a way i can tell rpm2cpio to convert all rpm files in the current directory? Im asking because rpm2cpio *.rpm seems to confuse rpm2cpio :-)

Comment: Sorry, never used it. However, you might be able to use a list and pipe it into rpm2cpio. Or write a bash script. Something on the order of for <unit> in *.rpm do rpm2cpio <unit>. (Just a logic statement. this is not actual code.) You can also convert rpm to debian packages with alien as I recall.

Comment: @ElderGeek That's exactly what I usually do, something like `for f in *.rpm; do rpm2cpio $f | cpio -idm; done` extracts all rpm files into the current directory.

Comment: @mtmiller That sounds like what the OP is looking for. Write it up as an answer?

Comment: Thanks mtmiller, thats exactly what i was searching for!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to extract the contents of RPM packages is to combine the [rpm2cpio](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/rpm2cpio.8.html) and [cpio](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/cpio.1.html) commands. This gives a command-line way to unpack an RPM in the current directory to get at the package contents, ignoring the package's metadata and dependencies.

For example, to unpack all RPMs in the current directory, use

```
for rpm in *.rpm; do rpm2cpio $rpm | cpio -idm; done
```

This will extract the contents to the current directory as well, and all files will be owned by the current user, much like extracting a tarball as a normal user.

The cpio command can only extract files to the current directory, so files will always be extracted in the directory where cpio is run. To put the contents in a different directory, you could use either

```
for rpm in *.rpm; do rpm2cpio $rpm | ( cd /path/to/dir && cpio -idm ); done
```

or

```
for rpm in /path/to/packages/*.rpm; do rpm2cpio $rpm | cpio -idm; done
```